# How to read this kind of csv?

Tags: r, encoding, readr

I don't know how to ask this question.

I don't know how to properly read this csv.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)


data_clubes_raw <- read_delim("https://www.datosabiertos.gob.pe/sites/default/files/Clubes%20-%20Renade.csv",
                              delim = ";",
                              skip = 4,
                              locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"), 
                              col_types = "t")
# output:

A tibble: 3,029 x 9
   Item   `Nombre del club`      `Afiliaci\xf3n` `Disciplina depo~ `Resoluci\xf3n d~ `Fecha de regis~ Observaciones      ...8  ...9 
   <time> <chr>                  <chr>           <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            <chr>              <lgl> <lgl>
 1    NA  "CLUB DEPORTIVO \x93C~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 21/03/2005       "Resoluci\xf3n N\~ NA    NA   
 2    NA  "CLUB DEPORTIVO \x93A~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 22/07/2005        NA                NA    NA   
 3    NA  "CLUB RASCAPLAYAS DE ~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 26/05/2006        NA                NA    NA   
 4    NA  "CASINO N\xc1UTICO DE~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 31/08/2006        NA                NA    NA   
 5    NA  "CLUB DE REGATAS LIMA" SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 2/02/2007        "Resoluci\xf3n N\~ NA    NA   
 6    NA  "ASIAMAR"              SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 13/08/2008        NA                NA    NA   
 7    NA  "CLUB DE PESCA SUBMAR~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 19/12/2008       "Resoluci\xf3n N\~ NA    NA   
 8    NA  "ASOCIACI\xd3N CIVIL ~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 16/03/2009        NA                NA    NA   
 9    NA  "ASOCIACI\xd3N INTERN~ SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 20/03/2009        NA                NA    NA   
10    NA  "YACHT CLUB PUCUSANA"  SI              ACTIVIDADES SUBA~ "Resoluci\xf3n  ~ 14/02/2013        NA                NA    NA   
# ... with 3,019 more rows
```

It seems that letters with an accent mark are read with another nomenclature so that "Á" = "\xc1", "ó" = "\xf3" and so on. I would like to read it as is (Á, ó).

Answer (score 1):

"Á" and "ó" do not exist in [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as plain text characters. Therefore the terminal will display that character with it's Unicode counterpart [\xc1](https://www.codetable.net/hex/c1). If you were to display this table in a PDF with a utility like Knitr, the special character should display as you expect.